# Model-View-Controller: SQL при переборе массива

Tags: php, sql, массивы, mvc

```
<!-- html-код -->
<? if(!empty($array)) foreach ($array as $val){ ?>
   <!-- html-код -->
   <?
     $id = $val['id'];
     $string = Database->select("
       SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE `id` = '$id'
     ");
     echo $string;
   ?>
   <!-- html-код -->
<?}?>
<!-- html-код -->
```

Использую на сайте MVC-модель. Это часть кода из View. Как видно, меня смущает запрос к БД, потому что это задачи контроллера или модели.

**Вопрос**: Как избавиться от запроса в View, если мне надо как-то выводить данные в цикле в зависимости от `$id`

P.S. Уверен, что этот вопрос где-либо разбирался, но я даже не знаю, как его правильно сформулировать

Comment: что значит выводить данные  в зависимости от `id`? будет отображаться другая разметка или что?

Comment: Нет. В запросе же видно, что условие выборки меняется. Сначала where id = 1, потом where id = 2 и тд

Comment: А почему нельзя сделать выборку `SELECЕ count(1) from table group by FIELD`? и будет у вас выборка каунтов по каждому полю.....и дальше результат уже передаем во вью и циклом разбираем

Comment: Переместите ваш код в модель и контроллер, а в представление передавайте уже сформированные данные. При этом выберите заранее все нужные ID в контролере и сформируйте в модели из них один запрос, вместо многих: `SELECT DISTINCT id, count(*) FROM table WHERE id IN [Список ID] GROUP BY id`

Comment: @AlexKrass только при `id IN` выберется общий `count`, а ТС, как я понял, для каждого id нужен свой count

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, только что изменил и проверил работоспособность кода. Выборка работает. Спасибо большое

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, для этого там выборка по двум полям в запросе, поэтому он не сможет их объединить. Вы получите пары значений `ID => count`

Comment: @AlexKrass я просто не заметил у вас `group by`, поэтому не понял почему так)

Comment: @FLighter по сути любые запросы, любой сложности можно сделать в управляющих классах.. просто надо посидеть подумать как-это сделать ..)